# How can I use the apply-Family, when the second function argument is changing along the same dimension as the first argument?

Tags: r, apply

Consider a function f(x,y), where x is a vector (1xn) and data a matrix (nxm), returning a numeric scalar.

Now, I have a matrix A and a three-dimensional array B and would like to apply f across the first dimension of A and B.

Specifically, I would like f to be evaluated at x=A[1,] y=B[1,,], followed by x=A[2,] y=B[2,,] and so on, returning a vector of numeric scalars.

Is there a way to use any function of the "apply" family to solve this problem, thus avoiding a loop?

Comment: `sapply(1:nrow(A), function(i) f(A[i,], B[i,,]))` it is *loop hiding*. I suppose in this case it is better to use a explicit loop.

Comment: @jogo Thanks a lot for quick response. Works perfectly.

Comment: Take a look at `mapply`. It was designed to iterate over each of the arguments in `...`

Comment: I'd say using `mapply` he'd have to transform his arrays, e.g. to lists of vectors and matrices respectively. AFAIK base R does not offer an elegant 'apply' variant to work over multiple arrays directly (without an index variable as shown in the first comment)

Comment: Thirded, `mapply` is the way to go.

Comment: @user3293236 I had a look at mapply before posting the question and since the documentation specifically refers to "element" I drew the same conclusion as RolandASc . Any advice on how to tackle the question with mapply?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sapply(1:nrow(A), function(i) f(A[i,], B[i,,]))
```

This is *loop hiding* because the looping is done inside of `sapply()`. I suppose in this case it is better to use a explicit loop:

```
result <- numeric(nrow(A))
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) result[i] <- f(A[i,], B[i,,]
```